# Why is the power for an object of mass m moving at a higher velocity greater than that for the same object moving at a lower velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, power

I understand the equation Fv but I will like a more intuitive answer concerning why the rate at which energy is transferred must be greater

Comment: You're transferring the same amount of energy in less time, so you must be transferring more every second. What else do you want to know?

Comment: -1. Unclear. Please explain your difficulty. What is not intuitive about the equation? Dou you expect some other result?

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way that for working against a constant resistive force if the object moves faster it covers more distance so it has to expend more energy to work against the resistive force per unit time.( As work done = force x distance moved )
Thus the power is higher for higher speeds.